# Make SQL query select only one of the WHERE conditions

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to run an SQL query in PHP that is supposed to return one row based on the following two fields:

1. first_shown_date
2. last_shown_date

I am trying to select the one row based on the following conditions:

1. `last_shown_date` = Todays date, if false then:
2. `first_shown_date` = 0000-00-00, if false then:
3. `last_shown_date` with the oldest date, this will be default

The query i currently have is giving me the wrong row, as i have one row with `last_shown_date` set to todays date, so that is the row that should be shown, but the row that is actually being shown is the one with the oldest date in `last_shown_date`.

I cant seem to figure this one out, instead of it being an "OR", it would ideally function as an "IF ELSE" statement, so that if rule #1 fails, then choose the next, but if rule #1 is true, then use that one and not the next.
I tried if statements and CASEs but they did not work as needed either.

Here is the code i have at the moment:

```
    SELECT 
    `id`,
    `content`

    FROM `".USED_TBL."` 

    WHERE 
    `last_shown_date` = '$dateDB' OR (`last_shown_date` != '$dateDB' AND
    `first_shown_date` = '0000-00-00' OR(`first_shown_date` != '0000-00-00' AND
    `last_shown_date` < '$dateDB'))
    AND `status` != 2

    ORDER BY
    `last_shown_date` ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Maybe use a `case` statement for which result to return.

Comment: I tried that, since both cases were true, it returned both, though because i am limiting it to 1, only 1 result came through, but the wrong one, i need the case to end or exit after the first condition that is found to be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the ranking in your ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY
  (last_shown_date = CURRENT_DATE) DESC,
  (first_shown_date = DATE '0000-00-00') DESC,
  last_shown_date
LIMIT 1
```

This makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0, e.g. when `last_shown_date = CURRENT_DATE` is true, the expression's result is 1 which we prefer over 0 (by ordering descending).

(By the way: Can a date in MySQL really be 0000-00-00?)

Comment: Nice! This is working, thanks for this, i wonder if there is any other way to achieve the same result. And yea you can add a date as 0000-00-00 in MySQL, i believe its the default value when you insert a new row that has a date field but no date value.

Comment: Why would you look for another way? Seems so simple: order rows from best to worst, then pick the first one. If you insert a row without specifying the date, its value will be null as for any other data type, by the way.

Comment: As of MySQL 8 you can use `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` to rank your rows. Then you write an outer query, where you only keep rows `where the_rank = 1`. This makes it possible to get the best row **per** customer/order/user/whatever. But the technique is actually the same, for all those functions have an `ORDER BY` clause you'd use just the same way as shown in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is very simple, i just wonder how else it can be done, if its even possible, from a puzzle solving point of view. And yes your right about the it being set as null! We just have it set to 0000-00-00 by default.

Comment: It makes me kind of sad that MySQL allows 0000-00-00. One aspect of data types is to guarantee valid values. You cannot store 1.23 in an integer column and you cannot store 'mouse' in a numeric column. You should only be able to store valid dates in a date column, not '1234-56-78' nor '0000-00-00'.